# Does AWS Kinesis Analytics have watermarks and sliding windows on other fields than ROWTIME?

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, real-time, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

After couple of weeks working with Kinesis Analytics I have a bunch of questions:

1. Does it have something like watermarks? [like in flink](https://www.da-platform.com/blog/watermarks-in-apache-flink-made-easy)

   As what I fount, even stagger window are emitted based on real time:

> The records are grouped by one-minute stagger windows. The stagger
>   window starts when the application receives the first AMZN record
>   (with a ROWTIME of 11:00:20). When the 1-minute stagger window expires
>   (at 11:00:20) {I guess that is a typo probrbly it should be 11:01:20},
>   a record with the results that fall within the stagger window (based
>   on ROWTIME and EVENT_TIME) is written to the output stream. Using a
>   stagger window, all of the records with a ROWTIME and EVENT_TIME
>   within a one-minute window are emitted in a single result. [taken
>   here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/stagger-window-concepts.html)

2. On the [page about sliding windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/sliding-window-concepts.html) I found some examples and as far as there you can only choose field for "partition by" I can assume that the only field based on which windowing is made is ROWTIME.

> WINDOW W1 AS (
>           PARTITION BY ticker_symbol 
>           RANGE INTERVAL '1' MINUTE PRECEDING);

Please don't consider this as post of hate, I am using AWS a lot and most of the services are reliable and user friendly. It is more an attempt to point to on some features which are maybe needed by some more users (not only me).

Or if you know how this could already be used in Kinesis Analytics, it would be interesting to know as I did not found anything about those features in documentation.

Comment: Did you find a way to change the field based on which the windowing is done to another timestamp column than ROWTIME?

Answer (score 3):

From what I've read in their documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/timestamps-rowtime-concepts.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/windowed-sql.html)

> For a time-based windowed query, you specify the window size in terms of time (for example, a one-minute window). This requires a timestamp column in your in-application stream that is monotonically increasing. (The timestamp for a new row is greater than or equal to the previous row.) Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics provides such a timestamp column called ROWTIME for each in-application stream. You can use this column when specifying time-based queries. For your application, you might choose some other timestamp option. For more information, see Timestamps and the ROWTIME Column.

you can have event-time windows, but the timestamps have to be monotonically increasing, which suggests that there is only simple watermarking. A search for watermark does find some hits on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/metrics-dimensions.html).

Comment: "you can have event-time windows, but the timestamps have to be monotonically increasing" I guess that is not what could be guaranteed in the situation when network is involved. More over their current setup does not allow to use sliding (not talking about tumbling window) time-based windows on historical data. I mean if you will reload data with some significant delay to the Kinesis application it just will not work, because application will generate new ROWTIME for every record and records will be grouped in absolutely new way, so no reprocessing of historical data in that case is possible.

Comment: "You can use this column when specifying time-based queries" -> I don't see a way of doing that for sliding windows. This is an example from the docs:      
WINDOW W1 AS (
        PARTITION BY ticker_symbol 
        RANGE INTERVAL '1' MINUTE PRECEDING);
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/sliding-window-concepts.html)
Which I guess is using the ROWTIME for the intervals. How do I specify that it should use another column as the timestamp column to create the intervals on?